# Can I mark a function as deprecated in Scala?

Tags: scala, deprecated

I'd like Scala compiler to show a deprecation warning whenever a particular function is found used. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Annotate it as [`@deprecated`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.deprecated).

Comment: And if you don't want deprecation warnings about your deprecation annotations, make sure you supply them with both `message` and `since` arguments.

Comment: Fixed link: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/deprecated.html

Answer (score 36):

I didn't notice the comment, kristian-domagala, so here is the example:

```
@deprecated("Reason this is old","01-08-2014")
def oldMethod = {          
  ...      
}
```

Comment: Now it's: @deprecated("don't use this", "01/01/2014")

Comment: The `since` argument needn't be a date, in fact the docs specify it as "a string identifying the first version in which the definition was deprecated".

Comment: @ToddOwen True, I find it useful to put in the commit hash there for example.